# How to remove anomalous warning after closing gvim

Tags: command-line, gvim

I have added the function `gvim(){ /usr/bin/gvim -f "$@" & true; }` to my `.bashrc` file.
but I still have a problem. 
I open file 111 with gvim and close it and
a warning like `[10]+ ... /usr/bin/gvim -f $*"?` is displayed in my terminal.
How do I remove it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have backgrounded the program by using the ampersand (`&`) and also it is probably best to name your function mygvim so you can still run `gvim` with its default settings when you want to.

cd to your home folder and edit your `.bashrc` with your favourite text editor:

```
nano -cw .bashrc
```

Your function should look like this:

```
mygvim() { /usr/bin/gvim -f "$@"; }
```

(If you wish your files to each open in tabs you could add the `-p` option.) Then save your file after you have finished editing it.

Now you must source your `.bashrc` so it is read (or restart the terminal):

```
. .bashrc
```

You can call your function by whatever its name is and place two text files in the `gvim` buffers with

```
mygvim my.txt second.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're running `true` after calling gvim. Its effect would be to surpress the exit status of gvim, yet I can't think of any reason why you'd want to do that except on a case by case basis. Anyway,I think the simplest thing is to use an alias:

```
alias gvim='gvim -f'
```

You could also use the function:

```
gvim() {
  command gvim -f "$@"
}
```

These two ways are equivalent.

As to the name of your function or alias, I don't quite agree with Mik. If you plan to normally call gvim in the way you mentioned, I see no harm in doing what you're doing. If you ever need the default behavior, you can easily use the `command` prefix. In fact, I've written a few wrapper scripts that are placed earlier on the path and completely override the system program. It's only a problem if you find yourself having to frequently override your customizations.